# SugarCRM GetAllRoles() to Retrieve Data for Custom Module/Page

Tags: php, roles, sugarcrm

I've been working with SugarCRM by creating a custom module and a custom PHP file to that module. I need to display all the Roles available to Users and have the data displayed on the custom PHP page.

I have looked in to getAllRoles() function and...

```
ACLRole::getAllRoles(boolean $returnAsArray=false);
```

Can any one help me get these functions to work properly?

**(Please answer only if you know the answer and do not close the question with false reasons.)**

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get all Roles that aren't deleted, you will find the method in /modules/ACLRoles/ACLRole.php. It will return either an array of array representations of acl roles or an array of ACLRoles.

The query is:

```
'SELECT acl_roles.* FROM acl_roles WHERE acl_roles.deleted=0 ORDER BY name';
```

Try this code:

```
$roles = array();
$roles = ACLRole::getAllRoles(true);
print_r($roles);
sugar_die();
```

Hope that helps.